# Can't Access ModelMap Attribute in jsp view

Tags: java, spring, jsp

I have just started learning Spring MVC. I have done my first project but I'm encountering a problem, I can't access the ModelMap Attribute via the jsp.

[image: Controller]

[image: View]

Comment: Use `org.springframework.ui.Model` instead of ModelMap.

Comment: Thank you for you answer unfortunately  but it didn't work, i'm getting ${g} as result !

Comment: can you post html code snippet.

Comment: @Lovababu here u go it's done ! anything else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i've found the solution i've added this : isELIgnored= "false"
to my Jsp's page Tag.